# Django Unit Tests returns exit code = 0 for pass and failing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, exit-code

My django unit tests returns exit code = 0 for unit tests (that are passing) and for unit tests (that are failing).

Because the exit code is 0 in both the above cases, I cannot qualify a build as a success or a failure in my script. Any reason why this is so?

Django Version: 1.3.0
Python Version: 2.6.6
Linux 2.6.35-28-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 18:42:20 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I am very suddenly having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when using django-testcoverage.  After disabling django-testcoverage

```
python manage.py test <app>
```

exited with a return code of 1 when failures occurred.

Comment: aaand a couple years later the problem is back. looks like successful fully-grown libraries can run longer than their maintenance windows, huh?

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/):

> Note that the return code for the test-runner script is 1 for any
>   number of failed and erroneous tests. If all the tests pass, the
>   return code is 0. This feature is useful if you're using the
>   test-runner script in a shell script and need to test for success or
>   failure at that level.

could there be something else going wrong? are you wrapping the test command in something else which returns 0?